# How do I find values close to a given value?

Tags: matlab, closest

I have `data  = [1 1.2 1.3 1.5 1.8]`

I want to find closest values before and after from data for this point, `b = 1.23`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 23):

Here is another method.  The vector `data` need not be sorted and `b` can be positive or negative.

```
[~,I] = min(abs(data-b));
c = data(I);
```

Comment: I just note that this doesn't work for `b = inf` and `b = -inf`.

Answer (score 11):

if the data is sorted you can use find:

```
i_lower  = find(data <= b,1,'last');
i_higher = find(data >= b,1,'first');

lower_than_b  = data(i_lower)
higher_than_b = data(i_higher)
```

Answer (score 5):

How about `min(abs(data - b))`?

Answer (score 2):

This method generalizes Doubt's answer to the case where there are multiple elements in `b` that you are searching for:

`ind=knnsearch(data',b)
c=data(ind)`

which returns the index (or array of indices), `ind`, of the closest element (or elements) in `data` to the elements listed in `b`.

Note that data is transposed because the set to be searched in needs to be a column vector. If be had multiple elements then it should also be a column vector.

Also, this method can be generalized to give 2nd, 3rd, 4th ... closest neighbors (see documentation).

It also generalizes to the case when the data is higher dimensional (If `d` dimensions then `test` and `b` would have `d` columns).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a little bit hacky and inefficient, but I use `interp1` to find the single closest value as follows:

```
nearestTo = @(x, xq) interp1(x, x, xq, 'nearest');
nearestTo([2 4 6 8 10], [pi 2*pi 3*pi])  %  4  6  10
nearestTo(sort([2 7 11 3 5]), abs(-3.5)) %  3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [1 1.2 1.3 1.5 1.8]

b = 1.23

find(abs(data-b)==min(abs(data-b)))
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything more than what was already placed in this post as answers.